# Why doesn't this django url run on Mac?

Tags: python, django, macos, opencv

I'd like to apply pose estimation Python code in url below to the Django view.
But it works well on Windows, but not on Mac.
127.0.0:8000/pose_feed doesn't work without any error messages.
I installed requirement.txt in venv, and Python version is 3.7 for both venv.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/05/pose-estimation-using-opencv/

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('pose_feed', views.pose_feed, name='pose_feed'),
    ]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'streamapp/home.html')


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')
def pose_feed(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(PoseWebCam()),
                    content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

cameras.py

```
class PoseWebCam(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # self.mpPose = mp.solutions.pose
        self.mpPose = mp.solutions.mediapipe.python.solutions.pose
        self.pose = self.mpPose.Pose()
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.mediapipe.python.solutions.drawing_utils
        self.pTime = 0

    def __del__(self):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, img = self.cap.read()
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        results = self.pose.process(imgRGB)

        if results.pose_landmarks:
            self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, results.pose_landmarks, self.mpPose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
            for id, lm in enumerate(results.pose_landmarks.landmark):
                h, w,c = img.shape
                
                cx, cy = int(lm.x*w), int(lm.y*h)
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 5, (255,0,0), cv2.FILLED)

        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1/(cTime-self.pTime)
        self.pTime = cTime

        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,0,0), 3)
        # cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        # cv2.waitKey(1)
        frame_flip = cv2.flip(img,1)
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_flip)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

home.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video Live Stream</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Video Live Stream</h1>
    <!-- <img src="{% url 'video_feed' %}"> -->
    <!-- <img src="{% url 'webcam_feed' %}"> -->
     <img src="{% url 'mask_feed' %}">
<!--    <img src="{% url 'livecam_feed' %}">-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please clarify: are there error messages (what are they), or are there *no* error messages?

Comment: try 0.0.0.0:8000 or localhost:8000 instead of 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz no error messages

Comment: @JyothiS the same error occurs